# Encountering "Another process may be using the default GridDB port" error during installation

Tags: installation, nosql, windows-subsystem-for-linux, griddb

I'm currently facing an issue while trying to install GridDB, and I'm getting the following error message:

```
Another process may be using the default GridDB port.
```

This seems to be causing a hiccup in the installation process. I've checked for other processes using the port, but I'm unsure how to proceed from here.

I'm currently utilizing a WSL machine, and my GridDB version is "5.1.0-39692 CE."

I have checked for processes using the default GridDB port I found it's 10001 (I am not sure)

My question is:
How can I identify and stop the process that's using the default GridDB port?
Are there any configuration files I should check for port settings?
Could there be other reasons for this error that I should investigate?